# Generate random number of 5 digits in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to generate a random number of 5 digits using assert/1 and retract/1. I already have the following code, but I don't know how to generate a number with 5 digits.

```
    draw :-
   % length(X, 5),
   random_between(0, 99999, X),
   assert(rnumber(X)),
   write(X).
```

Thank you!

Comment: `length(X, 5), maplist(random_between(0,9), X).`

Comment: `length/2` expects its first argument to be a list. `random_between/3` expects its last argument to be a number. You should read the documentation on these predicates carefully. If the number needs to be 5 digits, why not just `random_between(10000, 99999, X)`? Or are you expecting leading 0's to be acceptable?

Comment: @lurker, I think he expects leading 0's to be acceptable else it would be trivial... (he has already used `between/2` with first argument 0 so maybe this means he just wants 0 to be 00000)...

Comment: @coder if leading  0's is what's desired, then  it changes from one trivial solution to another: it's just an output formatting  question at that  point since leading  0's are a numeric formatting  issue.

Comment: If you want to write numbers out with leading  0's, then use formatted output, such as [`format/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2)

Comment: @lurker, I agree I think that's what the op was looking for...

Answer (score 2):

You could just do the random predicate 5 times, then put it in a list.
Something like this:

```
code(X):-
    random(0,9,Elem1),
    random(0,9,Elem2),
    random(0,9,Elem3),
    random(0,9,Elem4),
    random(0,9,Elem5),
    X = [Elem1, Elem2, Elem3, Elem4, Elem5],
    retractall(rnummer(_)),
      asserta(rnummer(X).
```

You can then later convert the list to a string using for example `write(Elem1), write(Elem2),`...etc